# DIV height to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

### HTML

```
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="logo"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <h1>Welcome message</h1>
      text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
    </div>
  </body>
```

### CSS

```
html{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
}

html,body, img{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}

#header{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 537px;
    z-index: -1;
}

div#logo{
    width: 385px;
    height: 141px;
    background: white;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#container{
    width: 964px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

I want `div#container` to stretch all over to the bottom, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stretch `body` and `html` too:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;    
}
```

Take a look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rdiaz/3LQvA/).

Answer (score 0):

In order for elements to reach 100% height they need to have a position applied to it.

So

```
#container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Depending on the parents positioning of this element will determine its height.

If this elements parent has a positioning applied to it, it will become 100% height of its parents. If non of its parents have positioning it will be use body and display across the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

```
html, body {
    height:100%;    
}
```

As it spans throughout the entire page then height wise.